# Parsing Tensorflow checkpoint weights/biases into C++

Tags: tensorflow

- In Tensorflow, while training the checkpoint files (ckpt.data, ckpt.index, ckpt.meta) can be saved. To continue training with re-using the trained variables, we can easily restore it in Python through saver.restore(sess,'*.ckpt')
- My question: is there any method to parse these files into C++. Because I am developing Machine Learning C++ algorithm using the pre-trained variables in Tensorflow and Python.

Thanks